# UIWebView child-parent window relationship in iPad app

Tags: ipad, uiwebview, popup, parent-child

So I have a sort of complex problem. I'm working on an iPad app for a web application. We have already created a mobile-friendly version of the web app, but would also like to have a native app, so that's the current project.

The app has a relational grid it displays with entities used for analysis. The way to add entities in mobile safari and other desktop browsers is to click a link on the top of the app, which opens a popup with a search box. The user searches for the topic, and then checks off which entities to add to the grid. The user then hits a button within the popup, and the window disappears and populates the grid with the selected entities.

However, I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to have the two windows communicate. As of now, I have a new UIWebView open up when that particular link is clicked, but the parent-child connection is not made like it is in the browser version. Therefore I can select entities to add, but when I hit the button, the entities are not added to the grid. I'm not sure how to get around this.

Another issue is that after the link at the top of the page is clicked, I attempt to add entities, and then I go back to the original page, the link that should trigger the popup doesn't work anymore.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your issue, i.e., how to make to `UIWebView` send messages one another, I would that by creating an intermediate controller.

Your controller would act as a `UIWebViewDelegate` for both `UIWebView`s and its responsibilities would be:

1. creating the second `UIWebView` (hosting the popup window) by intercepting `-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` (what I think you are already doing);
2. intercept the click on your popup window and then using `– stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` to retrieve whatever information it needs;
3. pass that information to the first `UIWebView` by means of `– stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`.

I have no information as to what kind of data is passed back from the second page to the first one, so I cannot be more detailed.

Anyway, I think that using a second `UIWebView` for the popup window will simply breaks the DOM parent/child relationship (because you have two of them), so you have to resort to some more manual processing or modify the design of your web app.

EDIT:

After reading your comment:

1. UIWebView is really greedy as to touches. If intercepting clicks on links through `-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` is not enough, you can resort to overriding `-(void)sendEvent:(UIEvent*)event` in your own `UIWindow` derived class; but this is necessary only if you mix a UIWebView and a, e.g., UIScrollView or when you want to handle multi-touches; look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532778/how-to-respond-to-touch-events-in-uiwindow) for more info;
2. here an example of how you can execute javascript:

   `NSString *jsCall = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"yourFunction(%@);", arg];`
    `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCall];`

You can use this in several different ways:

```
 `jsCall1 = @"var func = function(id) { var obj = document.getElementById(id); return id.value; }; func('dataObject');";
 `jsDataString = [popUp stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCall1];
 `jsCall2 = NSString stringWithFormat:@"storeDataFromPopup(%@);", jsDataString];`
 `[parentUIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCall1];`
```

EDIT 2:

A test suggestion: put the following code in your delegate class:

```
 - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)webView {
    ....    
    NSString* aaa = [_label stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"f();"];
    NSLog(@"AAA: %@", aaa);
 }
```

The HTML contains the following snippet:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>function f() { alert('called!');} alert('javascript OK!');</script>"
```

it will give you a first alert meaning that js parsing was ok, and a second meaning that the f function was called from webViewDidFinish. I did a simple text getting a web page and adding the javascript snippet to it, and it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Is there a way to intercept a touch event so that a UIWebView doesn't swallow the event up? I was having trouble with this earlier.

I'm also a bit confused on how to pass javascript information through the `-stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` method. I've toyed aroudn with it and executed some basic javascript function calls (alerts, etc.), but I'm not sure how to really leverage it and use it to pass information. The issue is that we need to call a function from one window in the other window (if that makes sense). The parameters are all strings.

Comment: So for example, in our second window, we wrote a function f() that is supposed to trigger a simple alert. However, when I call `NSString *javascriptTest = [EntitySearchWindow stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString:@"f()"];`, it isn't called. Is this incorrect? Or am I misunderstanding the ways the method accesses the javascript? 

Note: This is triggered with a UIButton that switches from the second UIWebView to the first.

Comment: Sorry, that's supposed to be @"f();". For some reason it won't let me edit. Also thanks so much for taking the time to help. We've been struggling with this for over a week.

Comment: Cool, currently in the process of trying it out. Weird issue though: for some reason webViewDidFinishLoad is never called after i click the link and the superview switches. All the other delegate methods run, except webViewDidFinishLoad and didFailLoadWithError. Any reason why this might be? Also, because the project is so huge and spread across a lot of people, we probably don't have access to the base HTML, we just have a lot of .js files we're working with (which presumably are imported into the HTML somewhere, but we can't place javascript directly into the HTML)

Comment: I think that when the superview switches after clicking the link the page has been already rendered, so webViewDidFinishLoad is correctly not called. My test was means in isolation; I got the HTML through NSURLRequest and then added the js snippet to it and loaded it through loadHTMLString. In your case, I would call `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` from the method intercepting the link click (and you can be sure that the HTML has been already rendered).

Comment: Can you please explain a little more what happens when the superview switches, and why that would prevent webViewDidFinishLoad from firing? The second webview doesn't get anything loaded to it at all until the link that fires the view switch is clicked, so it couldn't have been rendered already.

Comment: Sorry, I got it wrong. I thought the link click was on the way back from the popup (second) view to the main one (already rendered). If webViewDidFinishLoad is not called when it should, this is an independent problem from the original one and I would suggest googling for it. Or you can provide the code of how you create and initialize the second view. Anyhow, the list of comments is going pretty long and we will get soon some warning from a moderator. It is better to edit question/answer...

Comment: That's alright, we figured it out. Thanks so much for your help, we really appreciate it!