# Touch method is not calling in appdelegate

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, appdelegate

I am showing a UILabel in appdelegate file on navigation bar (Not exactly on navigation bar). It is showing perfect. But no touch event is calling on it. Touch is working only on status bar. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code.

```
CGRect frame=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];
backgroundImageView=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, frame.size.height, 320, 44)];        
backgroundImageView.tag=50;
[backgroundImageView setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
[backgroundImageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"music.png"]]];
[self.window addSubview:backgroundImageView];

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{   
    NSLog(@"in touched");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tyler states in [his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532778/how-to-respond-to-touch-events-in-uiwindow/3049792#3049792):

> There is a handy catch-all method in UIWindow called sendEvent: which
>   sees every event near the start of the event-handling pipeline. If you
>   want to do any non-standard additional event handling, this is a good
>   place to put it.

To intercept all touches you should use UIView subclass for your controller view and override hitTest:withEvent: method in it:

```
    - (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        touchedView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
        NSSet* touches = [event allTouches];
        // handle touches if you need
        return touchedView;
        }
```

**OR**

2) You can use:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(anyMethod)];  
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tgr];  
[tgr release];  

Before doing this, enable user interaction of UIimageView.
```

Comment: How to implement this in appdelegate file??

Comment: I am showing a uilabel on top of view from appdelegate notification method. Now i want a clickable method on it. How can i?

Comment: @shivam..but ur code forcing me to believe blindly that u want to achieve that touch evene on backgroundImageView...http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=74

Comment: Thanks @PKCode... I forgot to enable user interaction.. Now its working... :)

Comment: @shivam..good to hear that from you...pls accept it as answer,if it helped you..happy coding :-)

Comment: How can i change this UILabel view when rotate screen(Landscape mode). It is not showing on correct position( On navigation in Landscape mode)

Comment: @shivam..please post another question with explanation for more attention :-)

Comment: Please cite any wording you copy from another answer. I've added the proper citation in the answer above, but be sure to do this in the future.